# Create a PDF From a JSP Output

Tags: jsp, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a webpage with a export option to PDF. I have to display the contents of the page in the PDF. Currently I use iText PDF Library to generate PDFs. The problem is creating PDF with iText is quite a challenge. Moreover we get frequent layout/UI changes for the webpage, so we have make the same changes to PDF.

Is there any way i can convert my JSP output to PDF. Like for example "if we set the content type to contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel", a JSP table can be rendered as Excel document.

Comment: *"if we set the content type to contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel", a JSP table can be rendered as Excel document."* this phrase is technically wrong. You're basically fooling the webbrowser that the given HTML page is an Excel worksheet so that the webbrowser is forced to open it in the associated application. You're also using the fact that Excel (at least, the older versioned ones) can interpret HTML tables without complaining that the file isn't in fullworthy XLS format as per mime type. The newer versioned ones will complain with a warning.

Comment: JSP is basically HTML (XHTML, XML) once it reaches the browser, so achieve this for HTML and then use that code with a different URL for JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked Jasper Reports ? It has the concept of XML templates. Also same template can be used to generate Word / XLS / PDF/ CSV / XML output.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the iText code generation if you use it in combination with [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) (a.k.a. XhtmlRenderer). It's then basically as simple as:

```
String inputPath = new File("/file.xhtml").toURI().toURL().toString();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/file.pdf");

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(inputPath);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

You can find a blog with more code samples [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should check [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).