# Convert entire JSP to PDF

Tags: java, image, jsp, pdf, itext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a PDF From a JSP Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185151/create-a-pdf-from-a-jsp-output)

I want to convert my entire JSP into PDF format. I am using itext jar for doing this. I have seen the tutorials for this but I did not find any suitable information how to convert the entire page into PDF. All I have seen is how to convert either image or text but not the entire output page

Can anyone suggest me how can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest better see this link...
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3185151/1581858

Comment: If anyone has the urge to answer, I suggest that you do it on the linked question above.

Comment: I did not get the satisfactory answer. Can anyone suggest me a good tutorial or example for my query

Comment: You didn't get any satisfactory answer because the question isn't satisfactory. JSP is a technology that helps software developers create dynamically generated web pages based on HTML, XML, or other document types. Asking to 'convert entire JSP to PDF' doesn't make any sense. Maybe you're looking to create a PDF using JSP technology (which would mean you didn't pay attention when studying JSP), maybe you're looking to convert HTML to PDF, maybe you're trying something completely different. Whatever you're trying: it's not clear from your question.